# Minimum size of sublist

Tags: prolog

What i want to do is given 2 lists find the minimum sublist that contains all elements of the first list. What i mean is given `Sublist=[1,3,1,3,1,3,3,2]` and `K=[1,2,3]`

I want a function that returns me 4 which is the size of the smallest `sublist=[1,3,3,2]` containing all elements on `K`.

My code:

```
ping(K,Sublist,Min):-
      append(_,List,Sublist),
      \+subtract(K,List,[]),
      length(List,Len),
      ( Len<10 ,Len>3 ->
        Min is Len
       ;
         true/0 ).
```

This should return Min=4 when i use this query ->  `ping([1,2,3],[1,3,1,3,1,3,3,2],Min).`but instead it returns true.Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working predicate:

```
ping(K, Sublist, Min, L2):-
    intersection(Sublist, K, L1),
    list_to_set(L1, L2),
    length(L2, Min).
```

Calling it with: `ping([1,2,3],[1,3,1,3,1,3,3,2], Min, L2).` will return:

```
Min = 3
L2 = [1, 3, 2]
```

Is this what you were looking for?